# Picking specific numbers out of text file and assign to variable

Tags: c#, regex

Someone here at works needs some calculations done from some numbers within a text file. I know how to do the calculation but I haven't worked with text file before. So I spent the night reading and wrote a little something for the first number I needed but it doesn't work.

So here is an example of the file.

[image: Example]

So that first number that comes after `FSD: 0.264` I need to read that number and save to a variable.  The number will always be different per file.  Then I need the first `3.4572` number read to a variable. and the last number of that column as well which you don't see here but for the example it can be the last one shown in the image of `3.3852` read and saved to a variable.

Maybe I'm making this much harder than it needs to be but this is what I was playing around with

```
public partial class FrmTravelTime : Form
{
    string file = "";
    public FrmTravelTime()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sLines = File.ReadAllLines(file)
        .Where(s => !s.StartsWith("FSD:"))
        .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        .Select(s => new
        {
            SValue = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=S)[\\d.]*").Value,
        })
    .ToArray();

        string Value = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < sLines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sLines[i].SValue == "")
            {
                Value = (sLines[i].SValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT FOR @Ramankingdom**

[image: New Example]

So if you see here all lines have an ending column of `0.00` until we get to
`3.0164  7793   1   0   0.159   0.02`

So what I'd like to do, is edit what we did to skip everything that has a column with `0.00` in that last column and make the first non `0.00` the `info.firstvalue`  so in this case `3.0164`

Now I tried this on my own and used 
`var data = lines.Where(line => (!line.Contains(Data_Start_Point_Identifier) && !line.Contains(FSD__Line_Identifier) && !line.EndsWith("0.00"))).ToList();`

But that breaks `info.startvalue` and `data = dataWithAvgVolts[dataWithAvgVolts.Count - 1].Split(splitter);`

So I'd figured I'd check with you.
So I tried this but I keep getting invalid data error on `info.startvalue`

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo();

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(row.Cells["colfilelocation"].Value.ToString());
                var fsdLine = lines.FirstOrDefault(line => 
line.Contains(FSD__Line_Identifier));
                info.FSD = fsdLine.Substring(fsdLine.IndexOf(FSD_Identifier) + FSD_Identifier.Length, 7);
                var dataWithAvgVolts = lines.SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(Data_Start_Point_Identifier)).ToList();

 int index =1;            
 while(index < dataWithAvgVolts.Count())
 {  
  var data = dataWithAvgVolts[index].Split(splitter);
  if(data.Count() >1)
   {
    if(!Convert.ToDouble(data[data.Count()-1]) == 0)
    {
     //set start info 
     break;
   }
  }
 index++;
}
```

the reverse loop you can run to set the end value

Comment: Will the file just contain a single line with "FSD:" or can there be multiple occurences?

Comment: if the "Drilling Data   FSD:" part is static, you can just use `decimal.Parse(Substring(...).TrimEnd())` for that part. Then loop over the lines starting at line 4 (or 3, if the first one which seems to be empty is already skipped), and then it depends: are the columns fixed-width (then substring again) or tab-separated (then split and decimal.Parse the first item)

Comment: If I understand correctly, for each input file, you have two header lines, followed by N data lines. You want the described value from the first header line, and the first column value of the first and last data line? (Edit: and you have an empty line above the first header line)

Comment: U need to modify the  logic

Comment: @Ramankingdom updated w/ an attempt.

Comment: Its seems to be bad coding practice.

Comment: @Ramankingdom I haven't been doing this very long.  I'll keep trying but I'm not sure as of yet what's causing it.

Comment: Update the hint

Comment: I think I fixed it. I needed `data[1`] not `data[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code

```
class Program
{
    const string FSD_Identifier = "FSD:";
    const string FSD__Line_Identifier = "Drilling Data";

    const string Data_Start_Point_Identifier = "AVG_VOLTS";
    static readonly char[] splitter = {' ','\t'};
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result =  GetFileInfo("c:\\sample.txt");
    }

    private static MyFileInfo GetFileInfo(string path)
    {
        MyFileInfo info = new MyFileInfo();
        try
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            var fsdLine  = lines.FirstOrDefault(line => line.Contains(FSD__Line_Identifier));
            info.FSD =  fsdLine.Substring(fsdLine.IndexOf(FSD_Identifier) + FSD_Identifier.Length, 10); // take lenght you can specify or your own logic
            var dataWithAvgVolts = lines.SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(Data_Start_Point_Identifier)).ToList<string>();

                if (dataWithAvgVolts.Count() > 1)
                {
                    var data  =  dataWithAvgVolts[1].Split(splitter);
                    info.startvalue = Convert.ToDouble(data[0]);
                    data = dataWithAvgVolts[dataWithAvgVolts.Count-1].Split(splitter);
                    info.endvalue = Convert.ToDouble(data[0]);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //logging here
        }

        return info;
    }
}

public class MyFileInfo
{
    public string FSD;
    public double startvalue;
    public double endvalue;
}
```

Comment: pure code answers, have a very low explanatory value. They are also less helpful for other people with the similar problem. It would be adviseable to explain, why the problem arose in OP's code, how your solution solves this problem or circumvents it. May be you should also read [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Looking at the latest answers that you have posted, you tend to stick to the pure code format

Comment: ok. It's not a generalized problem. I just give solution was free for some time.

Comment: @Ramankingdom  Thanks so much for helping.  I'm trying to test this but I'm having some issues with `var result` this is not the main form of the applications.  Its an existing app and this code is just one of many forms I'm adding to it.  So I'm getting the multiple main entries error.  I tried placing the `var result` in other locations so I can test but nothing gets created.  What should I change in this scenario?

Comment: @Ramankingdom  Ignore some of what I just typed before I was confused.  So I just need to write `info` to a txt file then correct?  Do I need `(string[] args)` on main because that ins `program.cs` and this app includes many other features not just this time I'm adding ot it.

Comment: GetFileInfo is the function that will give you the desired result. the main function is not necessary. I gave it to test as a console application. You just copy the GetFileInfo method and use it.

Comment: @Ramankingdom how would you tweek this if you just wanted the `info.firstvalue` to be the first line that does not have `0.00` at the end?  such as `3.0164  7793 1 0 0.159 0.02`

Comment: @Ramankingdom so the `info.firstvalue` would be `3.0164` in that case rather than just the first one in the list.

Comment: @Logan first value from DataList which is 3.4572 from your screen shot

Comment: @Ramankingdom Sorry I don't understand.  And hey I'm sorry if I'm bugging ya brother, feel free to tell me to go away if you don't have time.  I tried adding another identifier to skip lines with `0.00` but that didn't work.  Right I'm wondering how I change this so that all the lines are skipped until the last columns is no longer `0.00`.  Then grave the first value.

Comment: we are here are answer no issues. did not get. what you really want to extract from line which represent data. Can you elaborate

Comment: @Ramankingdom I updated a section above for you in original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154341/discussion-between-ramankingdom-and-logan).

Comment: @Ramankingdom I'm there now, I had to run to the store but I'm back in the office.